# Problems parsing json in payload when recieved by API

Tags: python, github

I tried  `json.dumps` everything but still does not work. I don't understand what is happening. I am using the GitHub v3 API and I'm trying to update a file using `b64encode` but it's rejecting me like a bad date.

I cant seem to find the problem :0

```
import requests
import base64
import json
def byteify(input):
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        return {byteify(key): byteify(value)
                for key, value in input.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(input, list):
        return [byteify(element) for element in input]
    elif isinstance(input, unicode):
        return input.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        return input
def push_to_github(filename, branch, token):
    url="http://{enterprise}/api/v3/repos/dataWrangling/weightsWebApp/contents/test.json"

    base64content=base64.b64encode(open(filename,"rb").read())

    data = requests.get(url+'?ref='+branch, headers = {"Authorization": "token "+token}, verify='/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt').json()
    sha = data['sha']

    if base64content.decode('utf-8')+"\n" != data['content']:
        message = {'message':'update','content': byteify(base64content),'sha': sha}
        resp=requests.put(url+'?ref='+branch, headers = {"Authorization": "token "+token}, params = message, verify='/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt')
        print(message)
        print(data)
        print(sha)
        print(base64content)
        print(resp.text)
        print(token)
        print(resp.url)
    else:
        print("nothing to update")
```

I got this message back from the API

```
{"message":"Problems parsing JSON","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.17/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file"}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to use the `params` argument to pass the message?  The usual way is to use `data`, not `params`.  Also, if the API expects json, you have to use `json.dumps(message)`.